# Sending notification when update event occurs

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I could swear my code was working until now. I am observing an Item model and want to send an email notification anytime the `status` column is udpdate and it is set to `loaded`. To do this I am using the `isDirty()` method but my code doesn't seem to work as no mail is sent. Here's my code

```
use App\Notifications\ItemAlert;
use App\User;
use App\Item;


class ItemObserver
{
    public function updated(Item $item)
    {
        // check if product status was updated to loaded
        if ($item->isDirty('status' === 'Loaded')) {

            // notify all users
            $users = User::all();

            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $user->notify(new ItemAlert($user, $item));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need help to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Apparently `isDirty()` need a second condition to check which was missing. The correct code was meant to be

```
public function updated(Item $item)
    {
        // check if product status was updated to loaded
        if ($item->isDirty('status' === 'Loaded') && ($item->status === 'Loaded')) {

            // notify all users
            $users = User::all();

            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $user->notify(new ItemAlert($user, $item));
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps whoever comes across this solution.